# HTC One V without Sense 4

Tags: custom-roms, htc-sense, htc-one-v

I have an HTC One V with Android 4.0 and HTC Sense 4. Unfortunately, the phone is quite slow. I suspect for the htc sense and other unnecessary application.
Can I install android 4.0 without htc sense?

Does anybody have a link to the ROM that I need to use? My phone is a HTC One V on the T-Mobile network (HU) and I got it in January.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If looking for a suiting ROM, you might want to check [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575).

Comment: Glad if it helped! We've got many good resources here. It's always a good idea to hover your mouse over some tag related to your question, and hit the "faq" link ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can install any launcher from the Play Store. You don't need a custom ROM to do this. I suggest [Apex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbmRkb2VzLmxhdW5jaGVyIl0.) or [Nova](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS50ZXNsYWNvaWxzdy5sYXVuY2hlciJd).

It doesn't change anything on your system, fyi

Comment: Just try it like that, if your phone doesn't get any faster, I would suggest an AOSP/AOKP ROM.

Comment: Unfortunately, the phone is quite slow. I think this does not solve the problem

Comment: A friend of mine is using the One V as well, he also complained about speed issues. If you are willing to root your phone and flash a custom ROM on it, I would recommend that!

Comment: Have a look at the [xda-thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1551)